# Running a jar file from cygwin is throwing error where from commad prompt it is running, why? (in windows)

Tags: java, jar, clojure, cygwin

this is the command.

`java -cp clojure.jar;sum.jar CalculateSum`

**sum.jar** is a jar file made from clojure and java code.
CalculateSum is file which contains main method of java.

*error from cygwin*

**can't execute binary file, Error 126**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cygwin provides you with a *nix environment within Windows, so that you might have to change the classpath separator to colons:

```
java -cp clojure.jar:sum.jar CalculateSum
```

Comment: chaging ; with : is throwing another error, **NoClassDefFoundError** binary error is gone.

Comment: **java -cp "clojure.jar;sum.jar" CalculateSum** this is working!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
java -cp clojure.jar:sum.jar:. CalculateSum
```

If you execute in the place you have the root of packages for CalculateSum.class

Comment: **java -cp "clojure.jar;sum.jar" CalculateSum** this is working!

Answer (score 0):

```
java -cp "clojure.jar;sum.jar" CalculateSum this is working
```